# Misalignment of equations using amsmath

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, enumerate

I would like all my equations to be aligned to the left on the same margin ie. move the first one forwards or the other two backwards.
[image: 1]

The second 2 equations are inside an enumerate package though:

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2}
\end{align*}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Find equivalent fractions with the same denominator:
\begin{align*}
\frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2}=\frac{8}{10} + \frac{15}{10}
\end{align*}
\item Add the numerators:
\begin{align*}
\frac{8}{10} + \frac{15}{10}=\frac{23}{10}
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
```

So I am unsure how to get them to lineup as I believe the enumerate has a natural indent built in?

Code for testing (must be compiled using LuaLaTex):

```
\documentclass[14pt,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=10px, paperwidth=640px, paperheight=720px]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\titleformat*{\section}{}

\begin{document}
\section*{\Huge \underline{Addition of Fractions}}
\LARGE
\begin{align*}
\frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2}
\end{align*}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Find equivalent fractions with the same denominator:
\begin{align*}
\frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2}=\frac{8}{10} + \frac{15}{10}
\end{align*}
\item Add the numerators:
\begin{align*}
\frac{8}{10} + \frac{15}{10}=\frac{23}{10}
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a complete small document that shows all options used and allows testing answers. Are you using `[fleqn]` ?

Comment: you are using three separate instances of `align*`, each for one equation.  all equations to be aligned must be within the scope of a single `align*` environment to actually be lined up.  and yes, `enumerate` may be affecting this, but we need to know what document class you're using, as davidc suggests.

Comment: I have added code onto the main post :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, environment `enumerate` and others add a left and right margin, thus the equations are moved to the right.

At least for the first level of such environments that internally using the environment `list`, the following example resets `\mathindent` to keep the same position:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\list{#2\relax}{%
  #2\relax
  \advance\mathindent-\leftmargin
}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2}
\end{align*}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Find equivalent fractions with the same denominator:
  \begin{align*}
    \frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2}=\frac{8}{10} + \frac{15}{10}
  \end{align*}
\item Add the numerators:
  \begin{align*}
    \frac{8}{10} + \frac{15}{10}=\frac{23}{10}
  \end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The trick does not work for deeper nested environments, because `\mathindent` would become negative and such values seem to be ignored.
- The right margin remains unmodified.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the same method used by the AMS classes:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\def\fullwidthdisplay{\displayindent\z@ \displaywidth\columnwidth}
\edef\@tempa{\noexpand\fullwidthdisplay\the\everydisplay}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\@tempa}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section*{Addition of Fractions}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2}
\end{equation*}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Find equivalent fractions with the same denominator:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2}=\frac{8}{10} + \frac{15}{10}
\end{equation*}
\item Add the numerators:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{8}{10} + \frac{15}{10}=\frac{23}{10}
\end{equation*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Notes

1. The package `titlesec` is incompatible with `memoir`; use `memoir`'s features to change the appearance of titles
2. Underlining is not a good typographical device
3. Enormous fonts don't enhance readability, rather they hinder it. You already have a base font size of 14pt which is rather large. Don't use `\LARGE` naked in a document.
4. `align` should be used for multiple line groups of equations, not for a single one, for which `equation` is to be preferred.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. reason for the size is im transcribing it into illustrator and that size fits the final format best! I'll take the rest into account! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to align several equations you need to:

- have them all in the same `align*` environment
- add a `&` symbol in your equations where you want them to be aligned
- add a `\\` symbol at the end of each line

If you just want to get what is on your picture you can use the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
& \frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2} \\
\intertext{1. Find equivalent fractions with the same denominator:}
& \frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2}=\frac{8}{10} + \frac{15}{10} \\
\intertext{2. Add the numerators:}
& \frac{8}{10} + \frac{15}{10}=\frac{23}{10} \\
\end{align*}
```

and play with the `fleqn` option of the `amsmath` package. However this is not optimal if you want to have a longer enumeration since it is not automatic at all! To change that I found that it is possible to have an `align*` environment inside an `enumerate` environment (as long as the first `\item` command is before the `\begin{align*}` command) but not the opposite...

[image: Output of the code]

**NOTE** This output has been obtained with the `fleqn` option.